# Finding the Complexity of Nested Loops

Tags: loops, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm given the loop pseudocode:

where "to" is equivalent to "<="

```
sum = 0;
for i = 1 to n
  for j = 1 to i^3
    for k = 1 to j
       sum++
```

I know the outermost loop runs `n` times.
Do the two inner loops also run `n times` though? (Making the entire Complexity `O(n^3)`.

Where for instance n = 5
Then:

```
1 <= 5        2<= 5
j = 1 <= 1^3  2 <= 2^3 = 8
k=1 <= 1      2 <= 2
```

And this would continue n times for each loop, making it `n^3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a tricky problem, those inner loops are more complex than just `n`.

The outer loop is `n`.
The next loop goes *to* `i^3`. At the end of the outer loop i will be equal to `n`. This means that this loop at the end will be at `n^3`. Technically it would be `(n^3)/2`, but we ignore that since this is Big O.
The third loop goes to `j`, but at the end of the previous loop `j` will be equal to `i^3`. And we already determined that `i^3` was equal to `n^3`.

So it looks like:

- 1st loop: `n`
- 2nd loop: `n^3`
- 3rd loop: `n^3`

Which looks like it comes to `n^7`. I'd want someone else to verify this though. Gotta love Big O.

Comment: Hmm, I'll wait for more answers for complete confirmation, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sigma notation to explicitly unroll the number of basic operations in the loop (let `sum++` be a basic operation):

[image]

Where

- `(i)`: [Partial sum formula from Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?lk=3&i=sum%20j%5E6%201%20to%20n).
- `(ii)`: [Expanding the expression from Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?lk=3&i=expand%20n%20(n%2B1)%20(2%20n%2B1)%20(3%20n%5E4%2B6%20n%5E3-3%20n%2B1)).

Hence, the complexity, using Big-O notation, is `O(n^7)`.